# Is there a way to keep the Vim Syntastic error window closed until save?

Tags: vim, syntastic

I can use `:lclose` to close the Syntastic error window. This works when I have one file open at a time. Syntastic will re-check when I save my work.

However, when I have multiple panes open, each time I switch back to a pane on which I called `:lclose` previously, the error window reappears.

Is there a way to make Syntastic only open the error window on opening and saving the file, not on moving back to the file from a different pane? Or, is there a command other than `:lclose` I should be using?

I want the window to open automatically when I open a file...then to be able to close the error window using `:lclose`...then re-open (if errors) when I save (`:w`, but not check on `:wq`). It should not open for other reasons unless I manually invoke `:Errors`.

Right now my `.vimrc` settings are:

```
" Syntastic settings
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1 
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1 
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1 
let g:syntastic_enable_signs = 1 
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for `:SyntasticReset`.

Comment: @lcd047 perfect thank you!